# How to remove unknown script and iframes?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML page:=

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "http://localhost/Stats/Stats.js">
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <button onclick="test()">Test</button>

 </body>
</html>
```

But when I use Firebug on this page, their seems to be many unwanted and unknown script tags and iframes.
I posted a picture but my rep won't let me.

What can I do?i tried running it through disk (using `file:///` protocol) and in xampp (using `http://localhost/`) but no difference.

Comment: I'm actually not understanding: 1) What is the problem. 2) What is the output.

Comment: You'll have to tell what Stats.js is. That's the only thing that could add extra content to the page.

Comment: Or firebug itself. Have you tried debugging your page with the native web tools in your browser?

Comment: Stats.js is simply a small JS file which contains some methods for handling Statistics.It does not modify the DOM in any way.

Comment: And Yes I have tried debugging with web tools in the browser(firefox).

Comment: I suspect the solution is "Run a malware remover on your computer" or "Stop caring, you installed those extensions for a reason", but there isn't enough information in the question to tell for sure.

Answer (score -2):

Just give the scripts and iframes that you do want a class.

Then, after the page has loaded, look at the document to get a list of all of the (a) script elements and (b) iframe elements. Simply iterate through these lists and remove any that don't contain the class you've assigned to permitted or desired elements.

Here's a short snippet that adds an event listener to the 'load' event of the window. When fired, this function nukes any iframe and script whose class doesn't contain 'desired'.

The code contains 2 scripts and 2 iframes. After the onDocLoaded function has run, there are only one of each remaining.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script class='desired'>
"use strict";

function forEachNode(nodeList, func)
{
    var i, n = nodeList.length;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        func(nodeList[i], i, nodeList);
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded()
{
    var scriptElems = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    alert("initially, there are " + scriptElems.length + " scripts");
    forEachNode(scriptElems, checkForSpecificClass);
    scriptElems = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    alert("there are now " + scriptElems.length + " scripts");

    ///////////
    var iframeElems = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    alert("initially, there are " + iframeElems.length + " iframes");
    forEachNode(iframeElems, checkForSpecificClass);
    iframeElems = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    alert("there are now " + iframeElems.length + " iframes");


    function checkForSpecificClass(elem, index, list)
    {
        if (elem.classList.contains('desired') != true)
            elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    }
}
</script>
<script src='someInjectedCrap.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe class='desired'>
    </iframe>

    <iframe src='someInjectedCrap.html'></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I used this script.But even after the removal , the scripts re injected themselves.I then saw a div with `display:none;` extension.It was a ShopperPro div.I then deleted ShopperPro and it all went to normal.BTW I did not install ShopperPro intentionally

Comment: @Azhar, ShopperPro is an insideous adware "virus" that's possibly been installed as part of something else (such as those idiots at Adobe trying to force McAfee on to everyone). I'd suggest googling for `shopperpro remove` and learning how to get rid of it.

Comment: @paxdiablo Yes I installed it from Add or Remove Programs.Thank you.
I hate the stuff that installers try to do like "force" things into the computer( like installing stuff) or trying to make people download software through their downloaders.